# Select2 não funciona no adminLte + Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel-blade, adminlte

Adicionei um `Select2` no página, mas ele não carrega de jeito nenhum. Alguém já passou por isso?

Implementei assim:

**Página: cadastrar.blade.php**

```php
<div class="box-body">
       <div class="col-md-12">
           <label for="Disciplinas">Disciplinas da Matriz Curricular</label>
                 <select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="disciplinas[]" id="disciplinas" multiple="multiple">
                      @foreach($disciplinas as $disciplina)
                      <option value="{{ $disciplina->id_disciplina }}"> 
                               {{ $disciplina->nome }}</option>
                      @endforeach
                 </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
       $(function() {
           $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2({
           placeholder: 'selecione'
           });
       });
   </script>
```

No arquivo de configuração do *AdminLte* ta assim:

```php
[
            'name' => 'Select2',
            'active' => true,
            'files' => [
                [
                    'type' => 'js',
                    'asset' => false,
                    'location' => '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/js/select2.min.js',
                ],
                [
                    'type' => 'css',
                    'asset' => false,
                    'location' => '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/css/select2.min.css',
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

Só carrega como um `textarea`. Não aplica o estilo e nem deixa selecionar mais de uma.

Comment: Você abre questionamentos atras de questionamentos tem inúmeras perguntas em aberto, poderia observar e creditar aquelas que te ajudaram? poderia contribuir com o site ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente é só colocar as referentes `.css` e `js`, e com o exemplo abaixo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.select2-single').select2({
    placeholder: 'Selecione os itens',
    width: '100%'
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>    
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/js/i18n/pt-BR.js"></script>


<select class="form-control select2-single" multiple>
  <option>Item 1</option>
  <option>Item 2</option>
  <option>Item 3</option>
  <option>Item 4</option>
</select>
```

eu estou achando que está faltando colocar `select2.min.css` e `select2.min.js`.

Comment: Deu certo assim @Virgilio. Realmente apenas pegando o //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/css/select2.min.css e o //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/js/select2.min.js não deu. Incluindo os demais arquivos que falou funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado amigão.

Comment: Se foi util para você @JunioAraujo precisa votar nela e aceitar como resposta do seu post, leia o link: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/707/coment%c3%a1rios-enlatados-para-situa%c3%a7%c3%b5es-comuns/6972#6972

Answer (score 0):

Isso acontece direto comigo, uma forma q funciona comigo é add a chamada do cdn no head do html e add esse js na pagina q vai ter o select.

```
$("select.select-menu-color").select2({
    allowClear: true
});
```

e essse é o meu html, ele tem atributo em .net, mas é só adequar

```
<select asp-for="estoque.LinhaId" class="select-menu-color bg-grey" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Linhas,"Id","Nome","Descricao"))"></select>
```

Comment: Obrigado Renan, realmente só assim não funciona. Exibi o código fonte e tem os JS e o CSS lá mas estava faltando. Fiz como o @Virgílio citou e ai deu certo. De toda forma, muito obrigado pela resposta amigão.